# Powershell скрипт работает корректно, только если запускается из Powershell ISE

Tags: powershell

Добрый день. Есть скрипт Powershell, суть которого в том, чтобы из AD получать пользователей и проверять поле officePhone на соответствие установленному формату через регулярное выражение. Объекты, у которых формат телефона не соответствует требуемому, помещаем в массив, содержимое которого конвертируется и отправляется в виде электронного письма.

Скрипт отлично работает (как задумывалось), если запускать его через Powershell ISE. Если же сохранить его как .ps1 файл и запускать через планировщик или вручную, приходит пустое письмо. Скрипт запускаю так: powershell -file "C:\path\to\file.ps1". Собственно, код:

```
$UserName = "domain\robot"
$Password = "********"
$SecString = New-Object -TypeName System.Security.SecureString
$Password.ToCharArray() | ForEach-Object {$SecString.AppendChar($_)}
$Credentials = New-Object -Typename System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -argumentlist $Username, $SecString
$MessageSubject = "Invalid officePhone numbers format"
$SMTPServer = "smtp.company.com"
$style = "<style>BODY{font-family: Arial; font-size: 10pt;}"
$style = $style + "TABLE{border: 1px solid black; border-collapse: collapse;}"
$style = $style + "TH{border: 1px solid black; background: #dddddd; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "TD{border: 1px solid black; padding: 5px; }"
$style = $style + "</style>"
$Recipients = "support@company.org"
$PhoneNumberRegexp = "^\+\d\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\s\d{4}\s\#\(77\)\d{4}$"
$BadUsers = @()
$Users = Get-ADUser -Properties * -SearchBase "OU=Staff,DC=Company,dc=org" -Filter * | select -Property name,company,officephone,emailaddress
foreach ($User in $Users){
    If ($User.officephone –notmatch $regexp) {
        $BadUsers += $User        
    }
}
Send-MailMessage -To $Recipients -From "robot@company.org" -Subject $MessageSubject -BodyAsHtml -Body ($MessageBody| Out-String) -Bcc "admin@company.org" -Credential $Credentials -SmtpServer $SMTPServer
```

На этапе отладки скрипта (запуск файла с опцией -noexit) выяснилось, что после отработки скрипта массив  ***$BadUsers*** почему-то пустой. Похоже, что конструкция добавления элемента массива ***+=*** в массив ничего не добавляет. Хотелось бы понять где я допускаю ошибку.
Спасибо.

Comment: You should translate your question to Russian. Or post it on stackoverflow.com or superuser.com

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса как не соответствующего теме, потому что когда по-русски, то оно легче.

Comment: When you are on Russian site, you have to ask in Russian.

Comment: Хм. А если материализовать `$Users` перед циклом?

Comment: (Или вывести до цикла.)

Comment: Добавь в начало скрипта `Import-Module ActiveDirectory` в явном виде. Кроме того, в выложенном коде нет корректного формирования `$MessageBody`, может там где косяк. Для проверки советую сдампать $Users, $BadUsers и $MessageBody в файл(ы) прямо из скрипта, хоть захардкодить имена, и посмотреть, сколько и чего скрипт получает.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Мне кажется, вы напутали с переменными **$PhoneNumberRegexp** и **$regexp**:

```
$PhoneNumberRegexp = "^\+\d\s\(\d{3}\)\s\d{3}\s\d{4}\s\#\(77\)\d{4}$"
```

А ниже у вас идёт:

```
If ($User.officephone –notmatch $regexp) {
    $BadUsers += $User        
}
```

Переменная **$regexp** у вас нигде не определяется, потому массив, действительно, получается пустой.

Предполагаю, что в ISE оно у вас отрабатывало как надо, потому что вы где-то задали ранее переменную **$regexp**.